# When $P(z)=-\overline{P(\overline z)}\space \space ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $P(z)=\displaystyle \sum_{0\le k\le n}a_kz^k$ a complex polynomial. What conditions must satisfy the coefficients $a_k$ to have $$P(z)=-\overline{P(\overline z)}\space \space ?$$

Comment: *If only* we had a way to calculate $$\overline{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\overline z^k}\qquad!$$But alas, no one ever has unveiled the obscure magic which intertwines complex conjugation, sum and product.

Comment: Hint : if two polymials are equal for all $z$, they have the same coefficients.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: I understand your error (I did and I will do a lot) but I do not understand the $3$ "useful comments$ received.

Comment: @Piquito I cannot fathom their reasons. What I can see is that writing down explicitly the task at hand and reasoning of the algebraic properties of complex conjugation is a factual addition to your post.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli:   I have no objection to your win.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\overline{P(\overline z)}=\overline{\sum_{k=0}^na_k\overline z^k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\overline{a_k}z^k$, hence $P(z)=-\overline{P(\overline z)}$ if and only if $\sum_{k=0}^n(a_k+\overline{a_k})z^k=0$.

A polynomial is $0$ if and only if its coefficients are $0$, hence $P(z)=-\overline{P(\overline z)}$ if and only if $\forall k, Re(a_k)=0$.

Comment: For both, you and José Carlos Santos below, my apology for not putting the best answer which is because only one person can be given. I instead put an upvote to each one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's when and only whe every $a_k$ is purely imaginary.

If every $a_k$ is purely imaginary, then\begin{align}-\overline{P\bigl(\overline z\bigr)}&=-\overline{\sum_{k=0}^na_k\overline z^k}\\&=-\sum_{k=0}^n\overline{a_k}z^k\\&=\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k\end{align}because $(\forall k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}):\overline{a_k}=-a_k$.

On the other hand, if $-\overline{P\bigl(\overline z\bigr)}=P(z)$, then $(\forall k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}):\overline{a_k}=-a_k$ and therefore each $a_k$ is purely imaginary.